# Ruby on rails: Is it possible to nest partial calls/rendering like so:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, nested, partials

Assuming that the "books/book" partial below is being called from multiple locations (like: author#show view, categogories#show view, categories#index view) and i only want the votes partial called from the author#show view. That is, i want the books collection returned from the books partial (@upvoted_books) to each render the "votes/vote" partail so that authors are able to vote on a book from their author#show view. Is the following code or a variation of it sensible?

```
    <%= render partial: "books/book", collection: @upvoted_books  do |upvoted| %>
  <%= render partial: "votes/vote", locals: {category: book.category, book: upvoted } %>

<% end %>
```

p.s: I have tried this particular code here and it doesnt work in my project but i was just wondering if something similar to it could work but it doesnt throw any apparent error either. Maybe i was just getting the syntax a bit mixed up. I alos know a few other ways to solve the same problem but i was looking for something more elegant. Thanks in anticipationm of your creative responses.

---

update:

Thanks @Deep, for your very insightful solution. What I have done to solve the problem before is calling the line below from "books/book" partial:

```
<% if defined?(@upvoted_books) && @upvoted_books.include?(book) %>
  <%= render partial: "votes/vote", locals: {category: book.category, book: upvoted } %>
<% end %>
```

That works but i'm not sure it has some significant code-smell or if its syntatically awkward. What do you think?

Final update:

---

@Deep these are the views you asked for:  This is my category#show view     :

```
`<h1>Topics#show</h1>

<p><%= @category.title %></p>

<%= render partial: "books/form", locals: {topic: @category, book: Book.new} %>

<%= link_to "edit category", edit_author_category_path(@category.author, @category) %>

<p> Books you have Authored </p>

<%= render partial: "books/book", collection: @category.books %>`

 And this is my books/_book.html.erb partial now    

    `<% if defined?(upvoted_book) && current_author.books.include?(upvoted_book) %>

  <h5>Created by <%= upvoted_book.category.author.name || upvoted_book.category.author.email %> on <%= upvoted_book.created_at %></h> 
  <br>

  <%= link_to upvoted_book.title, category_book_path(upvoted_book.category, upvoted_book) %>

  <% if policy(Vote.new).create? %>

    <%= render partial: "votes/vote", locals: {category: upvoted_book.category, book: upvoted_book} %>
  <br>

  <% end %>

<% else %>

  <h5>Created by <%= book.category.author.name || book.category.author.email %> on <%= book.created_at %></h> 
  <br>

  <%= link_to book.title, category_book_path(book.category, book) %>

  <%= link_to "Remove book", category_book_path(book.category, book), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this book?" } %>

<% end %>`
```

As you can see, i refer to local variables book and upvoted_book in the partial.    This is how i called the partial from the author#show view  :  `

```
<%= render partial: "categories/form", locals: {category: Category.new, author: @author} %>

<p> Categories and Books you have Writen: </p>

<%= render partial: "categories/category", collection: @categories %>

<p> Books from all authors that you have Upvoted: </p>

<%= render partial: "books/book", collection: @upvoted_books, as: :upvoted_book %>
<br>  `

Thanks for you wonderful insight again.
```

Comment: In my opinion the solution is good enough, mine is similar just by passing locals and in yours you don't need to worry to pass that local from everywhere else. So I pretty much liked the solution.

Comment: Can you also please post your categories/show.html.erb? And can you please verify if the books/_book.html.erb is using a @book or something? I suspect a code smell.

Comment: `<h1>Topics#show</h1>

<p><%= @category.title %></p>

<%= render partial: "books/form", locals: {topic: @category, book: Book.new} %>

<%= link_to "edit category", edit_author_category_path(@category.author, @category) %>

<p> Books you have Authored </p>

<%= render partial: "books/book", collection: @category.books %>`

Answer (score 1):

As you need vote partial to be rendered on each book and only in a single view, so what you can do is:

```
<%= render partial: "books/book", collection: @upvoted_books, locals: { vote: true } %>
```

Now in your partial **book** write down:

```
if vote
   <%= render partial: "votes/vote", locals: {category: book.category, book: upvoted } %>
end
```

And make sure from rest of the places where you are rendering `book` partial pass `locals: { vote: false }` or else it will throw error. Or what you can do in the partial is:

```
vote ||= false
```

Or instead of using `if vote` you can use `if defined?(vote)`, so there would be no burden to pass it from other pages.

Also I doubt you have some wrong locals, not sure may be so correct them. But using this you can call `vote` partial on a single view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Deep, for your very insightful solution. What i have done to solve the problem before is this:

Comment: I edited the question to update my full reply as i could not send proper edited code in the comment box. Please check it. Do you think the solution is good enough?

Comment: Passing boolean local variable vote is a code smell and a burden for other partial requesters. Why should other partial calls process that logic?

Comment: @ChristianRolle Any other better alternatives? Also instead of this we can check `defined?(vote)` so no need to pass from other pages.  Or what I prefer to do is in the partial I do `vote ||= false`.

Comment: @ChristianRolle I have updated my answer a bit, any edits to it to make it better or any new answer for this problem? As I too have used this in my application so I can correct it.

Comment: Sure. Using defined?(vote) instead of if(vote) makes no difference. Using a boolean variable is code smell, anyhow. I'd rather go the route of content_for.

Comment: @ChristianRolle, I like the content_for option very much. I am implementing it now. Cheers mate